# Trying to bind column dynamically in a table using jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to bind column dynamically in a table using jQuery .but click  event is not working while trying to click 'btnASizeR' and 'btnWdDelete' button event is not working .Any idea would be appreciated.

```js
$(function() {
  var i = 0;
  $('#btnASizeR').click(function() {
    /* To check the count of already exist tr in WireDimTbl and then assigning the i value for controlids*/
    var i = $("#WireDimTbl tbody>tr").length + 1;
    /* To check the count of already exist tr in WireDimTbl and then assigning the i value for controlids*/
    var sizerangeMin = "<input type='text' ID='SizeMin" + i + "' name='SizeMin' value='2.00' />";
    var sizerangeMax = "<input type='text' ID='SizeMax" + i + "' name='SizeMax' value='3.00' />";
    var ToleranceMin = "<input type='text' ID='TolMin" + i + "' name='TolMin' value='1' />";
    var ToleranceMax = "<input type='text' ID='TolMax" + i + "' name='TolMax' value='1' />";
    var markup = "<tr><td>" + sizerangeMin + "</td><td>" + sizerangeMax + "</td><td>" + ToleranceMin + "</td><td>" + ToleranceMax + "</td></tr>";
    $("#WireDimTbl tbody").append(markup);
  });
  $('#btnWdDelete').click(function() {

    $("#WireDimTbl tbody>tr:last").remove();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td class='text-left'><strong>Wire Dimensions</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class='text-left'><strong>Standard Sizes & Tolerances</strong></td>

  <td>
    <input type="button" id="btnASizeR" value="AddSizeRange" />
    <input type="button" id="btnWdDelete" value="Delete" />
    <table id="WireDimTbl" class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="text-center">Size Range Min (mm)</th>
          <th class="text-center">Size Range Max (mm)</th>
          <th class="text-center">Tolerance (-)mm</th>
          <th class="text-center">Tolerance (+) mm</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Its working . What a real problem ?

Comment: but in my code it is not working where should i place the script code.Actually in my page i am generating this table dynamically using jquery and also at one palce i am using it in same way as i mentioned in this question .but dynamically where iam generating it is working and where code is same as above format it is not working there

Comment: It's more normal to have one delete button per row.

Comment: This has nothing to do with columns.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you are loading the table dynamically. Do you mean that when the page first loads the table is missing and its added later?

If that is the case, are you sure the code is called that binds the click events? The above example binds the events on page_load however, if the buttons are not yet available on the page it won't be able to bind it. JQuery will not automatically bind future elements.

Try settings a `console.log($('#btnASizeR'));` before binding the click event to make sure that JQuery can actually find the button.

Comment: on page load also this table is available and on clicking a button also this table is generating dynmically and in same dynamically generating script i have written the $('#btnASizeR').click(function()  function there it is working .what i want is same function is also fine for c generating column while it is loaded automatically on page load.

Comment: Does that mean you have 2 buttons on the page with the same ID? That can be the issue. 
An ID should be unique on a page, otherwise this might cause problems. As you can see in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/uqvvnxd5/ the click event only works on the first button, not on the second. Try changing it a class instead.

Comment: <table id="WireDimTbl" class="table table-bordered"I this table is existing on page load. and other is  created dynamically on clicking a different button on screen like this $("#pdfFormInsideTblRight").after(" <table id="WireDimTbl" class="table table-bordered">..function (  $('#btnASizeR').click(function() {) written inside this dynamic table .</table>")

Comment: But the page still contains elements with the same ID. As listed on [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) the ID should be unique on the entire page.

Comment: k so i can use same id variable as  <input type="button" id="btnASizeR" value="AddSizeRange" />
    <input type="button" class="btnASizeR" value="AddSizeRange" /> Then it is working

Comment: @hari the idea it to not use Id's, instead use classes and find the other parts 'relative' to your container. An example can be found in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w656ukgf/2/). I changed all Id's to classes and put an 'writecont' class on the containing row, then I iterate over each container row and from there find the required elements.